# Probability. Define Upper bound and Lower bound for double integral.

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, upper-lower-bounds

I am finding trouble of finding bounds for double integral for statistic.
Here the question looks like:
    given joint pdf = $\frac{3x}4$, $0<x<1,\;0<y<4x$.

I have to find pdf of $R=XY$.
    the solution is $1-P(Y>\frac rX)$ where $$P(Y>\frac rX) =\int_{\frac{\sqrt r}2}^1\int_{\frac rx}^{4x}f(x,y)\cdot dxdy$$

however, I do not get why the lower bound of first integral would be $\frac{\sqrt r}2$.

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You intended to write $dydx$ rather than $dxdy$.

Draw out the region of interest, $\frac{\sqrt{r}}2$ is the $x$-coordinate of the intersection  $xy=r$ and $y=4x$.

Comment: hi thank you for your reply. Could you explain why it is sqrt(r)/2 more?  since  i think If i plug in y=4x into xy = r, it will be x = r/4

Comment: @Ms.Ms you mean $x^2=\frac r4$

Comment: @DonThousand Oh, yeah... that is why i got stuck. Thank you